# HightLight Calendar in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm developing my website and I use PrimeFaces component.

But when I validation Calendar I can't make the calendar highlight.

Here is my Code. Could anybody help me.

Thanks in advance :)

```
<h:form id="addEditNewsForm">
    <pe:remoteCommand name="#{cc.attrs.reloadFuncName}"
        actionListener="#{logic.startAddEditNews}" process="@this"
        update="@form" oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.refreshCallback}">
        <pe:methodSignature parameters="java.lang.String,java.lang.String" />
        <pe:methodParam name="idNews" />
        <pe:methodParam name="action" />
    </pe:remoteCommand>
    <p:messages severity="error" id="newsMessages" showDetail="false"
        autoUpdate="true" />
    <p:panelGrid styleClass="newsDocumentPanel">

        <p:row>
            <p:column styleClass="width30">
                <h:outputText
                    value="#{ivy.cms.co('/ch/soreco/standard/xportal/Web/Components/News/Label/dateOfPublic')}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:calendar id="publicDate" pattern="#{swissDateFormat}"
                    value="#{data.news.publicationDate}" effect="slideDown"
                    navigator="true">
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="newsMessages"
                        listener="#{logic.dateSelect}" />
                </p:calendar>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{logic.save}"></p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: You aren't using any `validator` for your calendar component. How is it supposed to be highlighted?

Comment: Could you help me some example, please?

Comment: Take a look to this: http://qussay.com/2013/07/10/date-range-validation-with-primefaces-calendar/

Comment: Thanks all, but not working. Now I have to change my logic to check this calendar with required = true. And check when submit form. :)